# HKStatisticsQuery Out-of-Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I'm running an HKStatisticsQuery to fetch the total step count for the current day.

**The data returned is accurate only up to the last time I opened the Health app on-device.** If Health was not opened at all that day, the query returns 0 steps. This happens consistently.

It seems that opening the Health app triggers a statistics calculation or recalculation.

Are statistic queries always out-of-date? Is there a way to manually force a recalculation or refresh?

My code looks something like this:

```
// Request daily step count
NSPredicate *todayOnly = [HKStatisticsQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:[MYDataManager startDate] endDate:[NSDate date] options:HKQueryOptionNone];
HKQuantityType *stepCount = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];

HKStatisticsQuery *todaysStepsQuery = [[HKStatisticsQuery alloc]initWithQuantityType:stepCount
            quantitySamplePredicate:todayOnly 
            options:HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum 
            completionHandler:^(HKStatisticsQuery *query, HKStatistics *result, NSError *error) {
                // Return result
                completion(result);
            }];
```

I *could* use a HKSampleQuery and an observer query, but that seems to defeat the whole purpose of even having a statistics query. I've filed radar 19368739 several days ago, with no response.

Comment: I should have mentioned, that question received very little attention and gave no real solution.

Comment: The answer to that question is as authoritative an answer as you are going to find.  The behavior you are seeing is expected.

Comment: Which isn't to say that the behavior you would like is unreasonable but there is currently no way to do what you like to do with a statistics query alone.  Note that you can perform any query in response to the update handler of the HKObserverQuery firing - it doesn't have to be a HKSampleQuery.

Comment: I can do a statistics query in response to an observer? I think that might be an answer...hadn't realized that.